# Space of bounded functions and $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, solution-verification

Let $B(X)$ $=$ $\{$ $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $:$ $f$ is bounded $\}$.
Show that if $X=$ $\{$ $1,2...,n$ $\}$. Then $B(X)$ $=$ $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt:

If $g$ is a bounded function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then observe that $g(1)=x_1$, $g(2)=x_2$...., $g(n)=x_n$. Hence $g$ coincides with the vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$  with components $x_1,x_2...,x_n$. On the other hand, if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $x=(x_1,x_2...,x_n)$. Clearly then $x=f$ where $x_i=f(i)$. Since the domain is finite, $x\in B(X)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The notation or question doesn't make sense. If $B(X)$ is a set of functions, how can $B(X)=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @zugzug a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a function. In fact, if $[]_B$ is the coordinate vector. Where $B$ is a basis, then $[]_B$ is an isomorphism between the input vector space, $V$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the corresponding field.

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: Again, in your example, you are treating a function and its image as the same thing. For the mapping $v\mapsto [v]_B$, the output is in the image of the function. In the problem above, $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. The domain is $X$ and the image is $(f(1),f(2),...,f(n)) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you have any comments with regards to the comments in the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

The general idea of your answer is correct. But there is slightly confusing abuse of notation. Let $A(X)=\{f:X\to\mathbb{R}: f \text{ is bounded}\}$. Then $B(X)=\{Im(f): f\in A(X)\}$. Then we wish to show $B(X)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose there is a function $g$ such that $Im(g)\in B(X)$. Since $g\in A(X)$, we know $g$ is bounded so $Im(g)=(g(1),g(2),...,g(n))\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $g$ is arbitrary, we conclude $B(X)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Conversely, suppose $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define the function $g$ by $g(i)=y_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$. Then $g\in A(X)$ so $Im(g)\in B(X)$. Therefore, $\mathbb{R}^n\subset B(X)$.

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $x=(x_1,x_2...,x_n)$. Each $x_i =f(i)$. So $x_{()} $ is a function.

Comment: In other words, an $m$ tuple is a map.

Comment: I don't think we are seeing eye to eye on what the disagreement is. With $x_i=f(i)$, the vector $x$ is the output of the function $f$. In my field, it is considered an abuse of notation to call a function and the output of the function to be the same mathematical object. Anyways, this is petty and you obviously understand the problem so I am done.

Comment: I am trying to understand this. Because I am not satisfied with my understanding of what I initially know and your comments. I am not trying to be rude. What I'm trying to explain is found in page 35 of munkres topology. I am really grateful for your help.

Comment: I just wrote a solution in the solution section elaborating on what I mean. If it is okay, may you please look at it and perhaps tell me where my confusion is?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate on my solution.

Definition: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Given a set $X$. An $n-tuple$ of $X$ is **defined** by a function $\textbf{x}:$  $\{$ 1,2....,n $\}$ $\rightarrow X$.  The $n-tuple$ is denoted by the following:

$\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2....,x_n)$ where $x_i$ $=$ $\textbf{x}(i)$

From the above definition ,it is immediate that:
If $X,Y$ are sets. Then

$X\times Y$ $=$ $\{$ $(x,y)$ $:$ $x\in X$ and $Y\in Y$ $\}$ $=$ $\{$ $\textbf{x}$ $:$ $\{$ 1,2 $\}$ $\rightarrow $ $X\cup Y$ : $\textbf{x}(1)\in X$ and $\textbf{x}(2)\in Y$ $\}$

Returning to my problem, I claim that the following two sets are equal:

$\mathbb{R}^2$ $=$ $\{$ $(x,y)$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$ $\}$

and $B( ${$ $1,2$ $})$ =$ $\{$ $f$ $:$ $\{$ $1,2$ $\}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ $:$ $f$ is bounded $\}$ are equal (note, I set n=2 for simplicity)

Indeed, if $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ Then it is indeed an $2-tuple$ by the definition above. It is therefore bounded because the domain is bounded. If $f$ $:$ $\{$ $1,2$ $\}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{R} $ is bounded, then notice that  $f(1),f(2)\in \mathbb{R}$ and so $f=(f(1),f(2))$ by the above definition, is a member of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In your notation, the $x$ in bold is a function. The output $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ doesn't make sense. What you really want is to say for some $x\in X$, $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(\boldsymbol{x}(1),...,\boldsymbol{x}(n))$.

Comment: Let me try harder to identify the problem. In your opinion, what is the difference between:

$B(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb{R}: f \text{ is bounded}\}$ and 
$B(X)=\{Im(f): f:X\to \mathbb{R} \text{ and } f \text{ is bounded}\}$?

Comment: I'll now explain why I'm not just being pedantic. In functional analysis, there is a massive topic concerning bounded linear functionals. These are functions where the input is a function. For example, if $f$ is a continuous function, then $T(f)=f(0)$ is a legitimate function from the space of continuous functions to the reals. It doesn't make sense to take $T(f(1))$ since $f(1)$ is a number, not a function.

But yes, Munkres is a million times smarter than me so it may just  be a trivial abuse of notation.

Comment: I'm currently working on other stuff, I have set this aside and will read your comments later. I just wanted to say that I am so so so so glad for your help and I really do thank you. I apologise if I have bothered you.